# How to best secure s3 file for One User Only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I made a dashboard where users can upload files. I want to make it so that users can only have access to S3 urls that are files that they uploaded. How can I achieve this?

The users are application based, meaning they are, in my case, Django users.

Thanks! Anything helps!!

Comment: How are your users accessing the files? Do these users have IAM credentials or is this entirely application based?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams the users are entirely application based (django). Let me update my question to make this more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is entirely application based there are a few steps you could take to try and mitigate against accidental exposure.

Firstly organise your S3 folder structure in a way that uses prefixes for usernames, this way from a hierarchical point of view you can limit the scope of where users objects are stored. By prefix I mean the key might look like this `users/$USERNAME/file.txt` where `$USERNAME` is actually the users username.

You could enhance this in in your application by expanding to use [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/), with a seperate user for every user you have created. When the user logs into your application you could also have the login occur via the Cognito user (this can be done programmatically).

With a successful login you'll be provided temporary credentials for IAM, all users can be assigned to a Cognito group which can have an IAM role attached. When you login it will assume this role, which allows some special properties to be supported in IAM.

By using `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` you can actually limit the IAM permissions to only access that prefix of the S3 bucket. This moves responsibility from your application to Cognito and IAM.

More information about this is available in: [Amazon S3: Allows Amazon Cognito Users to Access Objects in Their Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html).

Comment: Thanks for this response, Chris. I thought of a potentially easier approach and wanted to see if this could work. Would it be possible to create a one time link to access the file? So, if I open the file once, no one else can open it again? So then I can't just send the link to someone else? If this would work, how could I do this?

Comment: Yes this would also work, but just be aware it can expire so you would need to ensure users have the ability to generate a new presigned URL :)

Comment: I see, I am not looking for something to expire, but instead to only be accessed once. Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately there is currently no support for one time tokens in AWS. In fact for a one time token you’d have to generate and manage the workflow for this yourself :(. If the users upload should they not be able to see there own uploads forever (assuming they’re logged in) :)

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have further questions :)